# AFNetworking download document

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have a web service to download a document using AFNetwroking v1.x
This webService accept Json as request parameter but response will be data if document exist else Json if there is any error.

URL: `https:.......` 
 Request Parameter: `{"docId":249}` 
 Response: `<25504446 2d312e33 0d25e2e3 0a>`

Don't see the response as i have truncate the same.

How can access this webservice which accept's Json but sends response as Data.
If i am using `AFJSONRequestOperation` then getting below error in response:

> 2014-11-20 12:21:35.379 DocWallet[2766:61355] Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
>       "text/json",
>       "application/json",
>       "text/javascript"
>   )}, got text/html" UserInfo=0x7d175bf0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=%PDF-1.3
>   %âãÏÓ
>   7 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>                          13 0 obj
>   <>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<4DC91A1875A6D707AEC203BB021C93A0>]/Index[7 21]/Info 6 0 R/Length 52/Prev 7657/Root 8 0 R/Size 28/Type/XRef/W[1 2 1]>>stream
>   hÞbbd``b`² ±H0§ 6G ñå#Ã4,#¹ÄÆ_

Comment: If you're accessing `https` why don't you go for latest version of `AFNetworking` instead of `AFNetworking` v1.x

Comment: Currently i am using v1.x and can't upgrade to latest as need to deliver the product

Comment: Which version of `AFNetworking` are you using exactly?